# Directive that checks password strength AND confirms match

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to use custom directives in Angular. I've produced the following as a result of lots of googling and tutorials. It's supposed to check

1. That my "Password" field input is strong enough, ie contains a letter, a number and is at least 8 characters in length.
2. That the "Password" field matches the "Confirm Password" field.

It works perfectly for the matching, ie part 2. However, it doesn't seem to do anything in terms of checking strength, and I'm not getting any console errors. Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong or suggest a better way of doing this?

I'm basing my strength checking code on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamdbradley/Qdk5M/)

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('match',['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

//This part does the matching

                scope.$watch(function() {
                    return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(ctrl.$modelValue)) || $parse(attrs.match)(scope) === ctrl.$modelValue;
                }, function(currentValue) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
                });
            },

//This part is supposed to check the strength

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {

                scope.pwdValidLength = (viewValue && viewValue.length >= 8 ? 'valid' : undefined);
                scope.pwdHasLetter = (viewValue && /[A-z]/.test(viewValue)) ? 'valid' : undefined;
                scope.pwdHasNumber = (viewValue && /\d/.test(viewValue)) ? 'valid' : undefined;

              if(scope.pwdValidLength && scope.pwdHasLetter && scope.pwdHasNumber) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pwd', true);
                    return viewValue;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pwd', false);                    
                    return undefined;
                }


                });


        };
    }]);
```

Here is my html:

```
<form name = "myForm">

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input ng-model="user.password" class="immediate-help" data-ng-class="{'ng-invalid':myForm.confirmPassword.$error.match}" password-validate required type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <div class="input-help">
      <h5>Password must meet the following requirements:</h5>
      <ul>
        <li ng-class="pwdHasLetter">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
        <li ng-class="pwdHasNumber">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
        <li ng-class="pwdValidLength">At least <strong>8 characters long</strong></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div> 


                        <br />

                        <input ng-model="user.passwordConfirm" type="password" data-match="user.password" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder = "Confirm Password"/> 

                        <br />
                        <div ng-show="myForm.confirmPassword.$error.match">Passwords do not match!</div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <a href = "#/home" ng-click="createUser()"  class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Register</a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above has errors (for one the `ctrl.$parsers.unshift(...)` part is *outside* the function; I guess these are typos).

Anyway, changing the parser function to *always* return the `viewValue`, plus a few minor changes that may not be important for this (e.g. the checks are not kept in scope, rather in local vars, their value is boolean, not `"valid"`/`undefined`), does the trick:

```
app.directive('match',['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
//This part does the matching
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(ctrl.$modelValue)) || $parse(attrs.match)(scope) === ctrl.$modelValue;
            }, function(currentValue) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
            });

//This part is supposed to check the strength
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                var pwdValidLength, pwdHasLetter, pwdHasNumber;

                pwdValidLength = (viewValue && viewValue.length >= 8 ? true : false);
                pwdHasLetter = (viewValue && /[A-z]/.test(viewValue)) ? true : false;
                pwdHasNumber = (viewValue && /\d/.test(viewValue)) ? true : false;

                if( pwdValidLength && pwdHasLetter && pwdHasNumber ) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pwd', true);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pwd', false);                    
                }
                return viewValue;
            });
        },
    };
}]);
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EHJq8/